# Magento2: How can I modify custom order number?

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I want to modify order number 000000001 to 202000001.

Please help me in this.

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-custom-order-number/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your database from phpmyadmin,

Here **_1** is used for store id after tablename.

**`Default Frontend store id is 1.`** if you have multi store then you have to set query for each store with table name like **sequence_order_2** upto **sequence_order_.***

Enter below query for table **sequence_order_1** is used for default store. If you have multiple store you have to set tablename as per store id in below query.

For order placed from frontend.

**sequence_order_1 is used for order id management in magento 2.**

**`ALTER TABLE sequence_order_1 AUTO_INCREMENT=202000001;`**

Next order id is start from 202000001.

For **INVOICE**,
if you want to change invoice id

**`ALTER TABLE sequence_invoice_1 AUTO_INCREMENT=202000001;`**

**For Shipment**
**`ALTER TABLE sequence_shipment_1 AUTO_INCREMENT=202000001;`**

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Open your **PHP Admin database**.
> 2. Find & click on the table called: **sequence_order_1**  (it is located in database itself not in the information_schema )
> 3. Click on **"Operations"** tab & under **"AUTO_INCREMENT"** edit to desired order number.

Comment: I will check and update you. Thanks