# 2.3.3: Moving to an updated version of a website

Tags: magento2, database, orders, data-migration, data

I need to move from my old version of my site to my new one. I have imported all the orders although I did this manually as the products structures completely changed. I would like to know a reliable way to change the auto increment of all the tables: orders, invoices, transactions etc so that when a customer phones up they don't have an order number someone else once had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First, make a backup of your DB.**

Then you can try running the following SQL statement to change where your orders / invoices begin:

`ALTER TABLE sequence_order_1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0000000910;`

This will increment orders starting at 0000000910 for example. Change this to whatever you need.

You can also do this for other tables as well, such as invoices:

`ALTER TABLE sequence_invoice_1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0000000910;`

For shipments:

`ALTER TABLE sequence_shipment_1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0000000910;`

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Magento2: How can I modify custom order number?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300397/magento2-how-can-i-modify-custom-order-number/300400#300400)

Go to your database in phpmyadmin,

Here **_1** is used for store id after tablename.

**`Default Frontend store id is 1.`** if you have multi store then you have to set query for each store with table name like **sequence_order_2** upto **sequence_order_.***

Enter below query for table **sequence_order_1** is used for default store. **If you have multiple store you have to set tablename as per store id** in below query.

For order placed from frontend.

**sequence_order_1 is used for order id management in magento 2.**

**`ALTER TABLE sequence_order_1 AUTO_INCREMENT=202000001;`**

Next order id is start from 202000001.

For **INVOICE**,
if you want to change invoice id

**`ALTER TABLE sequence_invoice_1 AUTO_INCREMENT=202000001;`**

**For Shipment**
**`ALTER TABLE sequence_shipment_1 AUTO_INCREMENT=202000001;`**